# Do I have my raytracing right? - LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, raytracing, trace

So, I'm desperately trying to understand ray tracing, and I THINK I have it...? What I think it is: You have a camera location and rotation, and then you create a simulated entity in which will move along the velocity equal to the 0-1(float/double) vector per coordinate, in a short amount of time, and in the end with a lot of collision checking, find and return a location depending on how you do the collision data? This is just my theories of understand, my question is, did I get it right?

Comment: No don't do that, it would be a lot more work, that using line intersection mathematics. If you remember from math we can create a line equation and then calculate intersection to that line. That is what you want to do. If you do that you can even get the precise x,y,z coordinate of all the intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of time you can invest in this, one idea is to get a working implementation, such as [pbrt](http://www.pbrt.org/downloads.php), and try to understand it from a higher level, as in, feed it an example scene, also downloadable, and debug the code to see how it goes parsing the file, creating the scene and its geometry, then sampling the region and creating rays, and finally evaluating the value for those rays.

You could easily skip the details so as not to feel overwhelmed.